# Ruby Gem Install Issues

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am using the 'stock' version of Ruby 1.8.7 that came with my Mac OS X (Lion) and when I try to install Rails I get missing header file errors. How can I fix?

Thanks

```
sudo gem install rails


Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h
```

Comment: Do you have the XCode "Command Line Tools" package installed?

Comment: No, I do not. Installing now... Thanks

Comment: Installing commandline tools fixed it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XCode "Command Line Tools" package includes not only the compiler, but the developer headers for many different packages, Ruby included.

The `gem` tool really should check for the presence of this before blindly trying to execute things, but that does not appear to be the case, and instead you get cryptic messages like this.